# Set textmate2 to save automatically with a .java extension?

Tags: save, textmate2

I was wondering if textmate2 can be set to save a file in a .java extension.   I'm looking around for such a feature but can't find anything.  Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following snippet to `~/.tm_properties` or to a `.tm_properties` file in your project.

```
[ source.java ]
saveOnBlur = true
```

`source.java` Refers to the scope of Java code from the official bundle. Your scope could be different, so to answer your question directly: you can do this with file extensions:

```
[*.java]
saveOnBlur = true
```

You may find this [thread/gist enlightening](https://gist.github.com/dvessel/1478685)